# peewee: ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: mysql, peewee

I'm trying to run my application with peewee on a server and it keeps crashing.

To start the application the start function is called in main.py:

```
def start(db_name, db_user, db_pass):
    BaseModel.initialize_database(db_name, db_user, db_pass)
    classA.create_table()
    classB.create_table()
    return app
```

It crashes on the first line in the BaseModel class.

```
from peewee import MySQLDatabase
from peewee import Model
```

I get the following error: "ImproperlyConfigured: Either sqlite3, psycopg2 or MySQLdb must be installed".

I don't understand the error because the database is running on the same server. The database was created using phpmyadmin.

When I test the application on my laptop everything works fine, for testing I use an SQLite database "test.db".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Peewee was unable to import any of the known database drivers.  Try running this from your interactive shell:

```
import sqlite3
import psycopg2
import MySQLdb
```

If they all fail with an import error, then that would explain your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer!
The server didn't have the MySQLdb driver, installing the driver on the server fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm:

1. click File
2. click settings
3. on Project interpreter tap  , select install button (Plus shape)
4. Search on mysql and install it
5. search on mysql-connector and install it